# JS basic design when I have naturaly sync code but I need to call a few async functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, node-mysql

Could you please help me to understand javascirpt async hell?

I think I am missing something important ☹ The thing is that js examples  and most of the answers on the internet are related to just one part of code – a small snippet.  But applications are much more complicated.

I am not going write it directly in JS since I am more interested of the design and how to write it PROPERLY.

Imagine these functions in my application:

```
InsertTestData();
SelectDataFromDB_1(‘USERS’);
SelectDataFromDB_2(‘USER_CARS’,’USERS’);
FillCollections(‘USER’,’USER_CARS’);
DoTheWork();
DeleteData();
```

I did not provide any description for the functions but I think it is obvious based on names. They need to go in THIS **SPECIFIC ORDER**. Imagine that I need to run a select into the db to get USERS and then I need run a select to get USER_CARS for these USERS. So it must be really in this order (consider the same for other functions). **The thing is that need to call 6 times Node/Mysql  which is async but I need results in specific order**. So how can I PROPERLY make that happen?

This could work:
/* not valid code I want to present the idea and keep it short */

```
InsertTestData(
 Mysql.query(select, data, function(err,success)
 {
SelectDataFromDB_1(‘USERS’); --  in that asyn function I will call the next procedure
 }  
 ));

SelectDataFromDB_1 (
 Mysql.query(select, data, function(err,success)
 {
SelectDataFromDB_2(‘USERS’); --  in that asyn function I will call the next procedure
 }  
 ));

SelectDataFromDB_2 (
 Mysql.query(select, data, function(err,success)
 {
FillCollections (‘USERS’); --  in that asyn function I will call the next procedure
 }  
 ));
```

etc..

I can “easily” chain it but this looks as a **mess**.  I mean really mess.
I can use some scheduler/timmers to schedule and testing if the previous procedure is done)
Both of them are mess.

So, what is the proper way to do this;

Thank you,
AZOR

Comment: The mess you're talking about is called a callback hell, and indeed, it's a bad practice. There are several ways of solving this. Have a look at [async/await](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9). It's a new syntax that is pretty much like writing async code as if it was sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of Node, you can use ES2017's [`async`/`await` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to have synchronous-looking code that's really asynchronous.

First, you need a version of `Mysql.query` that returns a promise, which is easily done with [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

```
const util = require('util');
// ...
const query = util.promisify(Mysql.query);
```

Then, wrap your code in an `async` function and use `await`:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        await InsertTestData();
        await SelectDataFromDB_1(‘USERS’);
        await SelectDataFromDB_2(‘USER_CARS’,’USERS’);
        await FillCollections(‘USER’,’USER_CARS’);
        await DoTheWork();
        await DeleteData();
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle the fact an error occurred...
    }
})();
```

...where your functions are `async` functions, e.g.:

```
async InsertTestData() {
    await query("INSERT INTO ...");
}
```

Note the `try`/`catch` in the `async` wrapper, it's essential to handle errors, because otherwise if an error occurs you'll get an unhandled rejection notice (and future versions of Node may well terminate the process). (Why "unhandled rejections"? Because `async` functions are syntactic sugar for promises; an `async` function returns a promise.) You can either do that with the `try`/`catch` shown, or alternate by using `.catch` on the result of calling it:

```
(async () => {
    await InsertTestData();
    // ...
})().catch(e => {
    // Handle the fact an error occurred
});
```